# Making a form in Access and I want to filter an input based on selected parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to enter data into Access. When I choose data source as "SQL" to filter based on selected input it is giving me an error: `syntax error missing operator`

```
SELECT 
CASE
Me.Regmen = '*First Line *' THEN tblFirstLine.ID, tblFirstLine.FixedDose
ELSE tblSecondLine.ID, tblSecondLine.[Fixed Dose]
END
FROM tblFirstLine, tblSecondLine;`
```

Comment: Access SQL engine does not recognize CASE. Use IIf(). Do these tables have a relationship? If not, the query will use Cartesian association and performance can be very slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce

Answer (score 0):

After the key word, "CASE" you need the keyword "WHEN", like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
Me.Regmen = '*First Line *' THEN tblFirstLine.ID, tblFirstLine.FixedDose
ELSE tblSecondLine.ID, tblSecondLine.[Fixed Dose]
END
FROM tblFirstLine, tblSecondLine;
```

Comment: MS Access doesn't do CASE. Use IIF or Switch.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and the database dose what it is suppose to do. thank you again